# Stacking EOS on Block Producers Account

Tags: tokens, staking, bp

I was verifying the amount of EOS staked by BPs. After going through a number of them its seems they have not staked most of their EOS to the NET.

- https://eosflare.io/account/starteosiobp
- https://eosflare.io/account/eoshuobipool
- https://eosflare.io/account/eoscanadacom
- ...

  As far as I understand their votes could increase the low number of staked votes we currently have on the system (currently at 22%).

Are the block producers restricted from staking a significant amount of their EOS tokens?

Comment: they may just need liquid eos for costs

Comment: @confused00 thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the block producers restricted from staking a significant amount of their EOS tokens?

No.

I think @confused00 is right, EOS is the income for BPs, so they leave it liquid to pay for their operating costs.

Comment: yeah and bps voting too much with block rewards may be sufficiently politically interpretabile/ambiguous in some contexts that some may prefer to keep away unless strictly necessary